# How to store cookies in crossdomain operation of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I want to develop a small javascript tool for browsers.

This tool can extract some content from current webpage and submit it to another site.

The whole work flow is divided into 3 stages.

The first stage is to extract content from current page.

The second stage is to log in. The user needs to enter their username and password in a login form.

The third stage is to submit the content abstracted from the first stage.

My problem is that the third stage needs the cookie from the second stage.

I have tried iframe, but failed.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies need to be, at least, on the same top domain and the cookie set to be visible up to the top domain. If you are on another domain, this is not a viable option.

Another way you can pass data is via a form submit. Assuming you are on a page on a foreign domain, using this technique, you can have your script build a login form that submits to your site, along with the data you gathered. It also means the 2nd and 3rd step is merged. No cookies needed.